# DB2 SQL Exception code 440 using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am trying to call a stored procedure from my java code and I am getting an sql exception.
here is my code snippet

```
 CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call stroredprocname(?,?,?)}");
                cstmt.setString(1, filePattern);
                cstmt.setString(2, fromDate);
                cstmt.setString(3, toDate);

                ResultSet resultSet = cstmt.executeQuery();
```

this is the error code i am getting:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -440, SQLSTATE: 42884, SQLERRMC: stroredprocname;PROCEDURE
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.e(tf.java:1680)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.a(tf.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.h(jb.java:139)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.d(jb.java:71)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.d(w.java:54)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.cc.i(cc.java:208)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.o(tf.java:1236)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.uf.ib(uf.java:1831)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.uf.d(uf.java:2296)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.Z(vf.java:159)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.execute(vf.java:142)
    at MyClass(MyClass.java:102)
```

Could some please help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you test(compile) your pl/sql in db itself?

Comment: The error above means it cannot find the store procedure.If it compile properly then I am sure that you have to provide schema name and proc name for example: call schemaname.stroredprocname(?,?,?)

Comment: Yes I compiled this in the DB itself. I tried giving the schema name as well it gave me an error like this now com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -313, SQLSTATE: 07001, SQLERRMC: null
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.d(tf.java:1396)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.l(jb.java:367)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.jb.e(jb.java:92)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.w.e(w.java:72)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.cc.h(cc.java:203)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tf.q(tf.java:1363)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.uf.d(uf.java:2388)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.X(vf.java:188)
 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.vf.executeQuery(vf.java:171)

Comment: That's good, Please find the schema name and add to the code when calling store proc as I have mentioned in answer.It will work like charm.

Comment: What is your query look like? Can you please check the params? params mismatch most likely?

Comment: Sorry I am very new stackoverflow so my comments are a bit crude. :/   I had tried a simple select query(to test the connection) on the DB2 db and it worked with no issues. Now when I am trying to call a stored procedure I am getting this sort of issues. This is the code I am currently using to call the stored procedure. There were some out parameters in the stored procedure that i missed out  CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call schemaname.stroredprocname(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

Comment: If you can provide me your Stor proc query that way I can match that to your java code and find the issue. Initially there was error 440 due to missing schema name and I believe this new error 313 because of params in query and java code not matching each other.

Comment: For out parameters you need to use something like this example cstmt.registerOutParameter(whatever you want here);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Definition 440 - Cannot find the store procedure location which means you have missed something which is schema name in your case.

Please add schema name right before the Procedure name for example:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call schemaname.stroredprocname(?,?,?)}");
```

2nd Issue Error 313 - Parameters are not matching between your PL/SQL query and Java code.

Comment: Hi Lokesh. Thank you much for answering my question so promptly! may i know if you have a reference of the error codes and what they mean? i resolved the error 313 by correcting the params now i am getting this com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null

Comment: Well you can see at the very end it says null and Secondly, you can Google some of the error code as well,will give you some clue.Please upvote and mark the answer if it solved your issue. I am also a new developer who is constantly learning and sharing my knowledge over stack overflow.

Comment: This new error is causing because Data being inserted into the database table column is larger than the assigned column length. Reference link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21585238. In order to solve this go to database and increase the length of column.

Comment: I think you are trying to insert something into database?